# Localizing folders on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have two csv files. I need to parse one of the files based on language selected on device. I have put those in Resources folder and created two folders using qualifiers(en-US, da-DK). Inside these two folders, i have put two files with same name(e.g. answers.csv). When i run application, it says that it could not find the file.

i used following code to convert the file into StreamReader

```
        StorageFolder installationFolder = Util.CommonUtils.getAppLocation();
        StorageFile file = await installationFolder.GetFileAsync(path);
        Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: AFAIK, if you want to access directly the files like you do, you have to handle the localization yourself. Retrieve the current culture (`CultureInfo.GetCurrentCulture()`) and manually the qualifier to the path

Comment: i was looking for a shortcut to handle things automatically.. like in Android i can put the files in seperate folders for different language

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are not using the [standard](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/02/01/tips-for-localizing-windows-phone-8-xaml-apps-part1.aspx) resx approach? That way the OS would handle loading/parsing the file for you..

Comment: the file i am using contains multiple lines seperated by comma .. in that case how do i use resx approach. i am kind of new to windows phone development. I have already used resx approach for word by word translations but a file containing large number of lines, is resx approach appropriate?

Comment: Well, you could store a path to each language's file in your `.resx`/`.resw`, then retrieve the current value for the `path` and use that as your file location.